# Problemas com datas FullCalendar Jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Estou tendo problemas com as data para salvar no banco.
Para que eu consiga salvar a data deveria vir assim:

```
2017-01-09 19:39:12
```

Porém ela esta vindo assim:

```
Thu Jan 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

A configuração de meu fullcallendar esta assim:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
          $("#addEvent").show();
          $("#editEvent").hide();
          $("#addNew-event").modal("show");
          $("#addNew-event input:text").val("");
          $("#getStart").val(start);
          $("#getEnt").val(end);
      },
      eventClick: function(event, element) {
          $("#addEvent").hide()
          $("#editEvent").show().data("ev", event);
          $("#addNew-event").modal("show");
          $("#addNew-event input:text").val("");
          $("#eventName").val(event.title);
      }
  });
```

O que devo fazer para que estas datas seja efetivada conforme preciso salvar no banco ?

O problema se encontra quando preciso recarregar os dados na API. Pois ai ele precisa aceitar o formato normal que salva no banco.

O que fazer ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a solução é utilizar o [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) do moment.js.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      ...
      $("#getStart").val(moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
      $("#getEnt").val(moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
  }
...
});
```

Lá ainda tem outras formas de formatar a data.